# create new ionic project error with node-sass

Tags: node.js, angularjs, ionic-framework, npm, node-sass

I'm trying to create new app using ionic v1 and I have the below errors
the following is my environment details

Environment:

- Windows 11
- Nodejs : v16.13.1
- npm : v8.3.0
- java: v1.8.0_311
- android studio: 2020.3.1
- cordova : v11.0.0

error details:

```
3232 error code 1
3233 error path C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\node-sass
3234 error command failed
3235 error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
3236 error Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
3237 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
3237 error gyp verb cli [
3237 error gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
3237 error gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\amrel\\todo\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
3237 error gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
3237 error gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
3237 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
3237 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
3237 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
3237 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
3237 error gyp verb cli ]
3237 error gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
3237 error gyp info using node@16.13.1 | win32 | x64
3237 error gyp verb command rebuild []
3237 error gyp verb command clean []
3237 error gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
3237 error gyp verb command configure []
3237 error gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed }
3237 error gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
3237 error gyp verb `which` failed }
3237 error gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher 
3237 error gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location 
3237 error gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
3237 error gyp ERR! configure error 
3237 error gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
3237 error gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
3237 error gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
3237 error gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:299:20)
3237 error gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
3237 error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
3237 error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\amrel\\todo\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
3237 error gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\amrel\todo\node_modules\node-sass
3237 error gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
3237 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
3237 error gyp ERR! not ok 
3237 error Build failed with error code: 1
3238 verbose exit 1
3239 timing npm Completed in 11607ms
3240 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1640215769849
3241 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1640215777883
3242 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1640215777884
3243 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1640215777885
3244 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall 1640215778890
3245 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall:node_modules/node-sass 1640215778890
3246 verbose code 1
3247 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
3247 error     C:\Users\amrel\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-22T23_29_29_495Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Why use ionic version 1? why not use the newest version? either 3 up to 6 :)

Comment: I already have app built on v1 and I can't build it, it serves but can't build it to get the package so I tried to create new app to check the environment but also I got those errors.

Comment: Do yo have python installed on your PC? seems like the error is connected to python
`Python executable "python" in the PATH 3237 error gyp verb which failed Error: not found: python 3237 error gyp verb which failed at getNotFoundError`
And it might be the python version.

Comment: My suspect is:
* it might be due to node version you are using
* The node-sass it self fails
* Their might be other dependencies that aren't fetch
* Missing commands
* Compatibility issues

If you still know the node version that your project, better to use it.

Comment: these are my versions :
gradle: 6.0.1
nodejs: 14.15.4
npm: 6.14.10

Comment: Im not so sure if yarn works better on windows, I also having problem with npm, thats why I switch to yarn

Comment: @Forbidden any documentation for using yarn for building ionic app.

Comment: Nope, but npm and yarn are the same, you have to install it first , `npm install yarn` then `yarn install` to install node modules, then you can run `ionic serve`